# Including a clickable link in sms message using Twilio

Tags: sms, twilio

I have a Twilio number that is setup to execute a webhook when a message is received. I would like to include a link in the response I send back to the user. ie.

Please login to XYZ.com at https://login.xyz.com/?client=SMS&userid=abc

However, when i send this in reply I get a schema validation error in the     Twilio debugger with the following message.

```
Warning - 12200

Schema validation warning

The provided XML does not conform to the Twilio Markup XML schema. Please refer to the specific error and correct the problem.
```

This is the message body:

```
<Response>
    <Message>Please login to Botler at 'https://login.xyz.com/?client=Twilio&userid=foobar'</Message>
</Response>
```

I tried url encoding the url and I no longer get a schema validation error however the link in the sms is not clickable (it contains all of the escape characters).

How can i send a link in SMS and have it be clickable by the user?

Thanks.

**Solution**

After much trial and error I found a solution that works. I can wrap the url in CDATA element and it passes schema validation and the link is correctly interpreted by phones.
For example,

```
<Response>
    <Message>Please login to Botler at <![CDATA[https://login.xyz.com/?client=Twilio&userid=foobar]]></Message>
</Response>
```

Comment: Solution was found and original post edited to include the solution.

Comment: you should post it as an answer and mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

The SMS is just text. The device has to get that text and detect that is a link to make it clickeable.

Following the doc [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/12200) the problem is caused by:

- misspelled verbs
- incorrect case for verbs
- misspelled or unknown attributes
- unknown or unexpected nested elements.

Hope this help.

Comment: I understand why it doesnt work in the current form. The phone does not recognize an escaped url as a url and if i dont escape it, the schema validation fails so I'm wondering how to i format the xml response to pass my string literal rather than normal content (which would fail validation)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the single quotes, try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Message>Please login to Botler at https://login.xyz.com/?client=Twilio&amp;userid=foobar</Message>
</Response>
```

Comment: Still fails schema validation. After much trial and error I found a way to do it. I'll add the answser into my original post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems links are clickable (e.g. on iOS 11.2.x) if sent on their own line.

In PhP (make sure you have twilio SDK - e.g. from composer install:

% composer require twilio/sdk

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
use Twilio\Twiml;

$response = new Twiml();
$response->message("Your message without href");
$response->message("https://.......");

echo $response; 
?>
```